# How would I write a syntax checker?

Tags: ruby, parsing, compilation

I am interested in writing a syntax checker for a language.  Basically what I want to do is make a cli tool that will take an input file, and then write errors that it finds.  The language I would want to parse is basically similar to Turing, and it is rather ugly and sometimes a pain to work with.  The only other syntax checker for it must be used

What language should I use?  I figured I would write it in Ruby, but Python may be faster or have better parsing libraries.

What libraries should I use, in Ruby or Pearl?  Which would be easier.

Is there a primer to read for defining a grammar?  Such a task can become confusing, and I'm not sure how I would handle it.

Comment: This is what I, and many others, read on the subject: [The Dragon Book](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886)

Comment: @ed-s - I have heard of The Dragon Book before, but I always thought it was only using C.  Is this true, or is it more generic?  I also thought it was geared towards compiling to machine code, but I want to compile to another language.

Comment: Why is this tagged php? I'll remove this tag.

Comment: I don't think, that speed will be a real problem. How big are the programs you want to check? Just think, language A would have the double speed to B. When A needs 10 seconds, B needs 20 seconds - would this be problem for a syntax checker? Speed may be a problem for real time tasks, but for a syntax checker? And most often I had problems with speed, it was not the language, it was the algorithm.

Comment: @sickle: Well it actually uses a mix of C syntax and pseudo code, but that's not important; the concepts are what matter.  As long as you can understand those you can implement them in any language.  That said, you're not going to write a compiler in python.  I mean, you can, but it's probably not wise for performance reasons.  You can certainly pull of a simple syntax highlighter though, you just need to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would write it in Ruby, and worry about speed later. If the program is a runaway hit, I might add a native gem to speed up the slowest bit, but leave most of it in Ruby. If it becomes the most important program in the world, or if I had nothing else to do, I might rewrite it in C or C++ at that point, but not before.

And I would do all [parsing using Treetop.](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/)

I might add that writing and optimizing a language parser directly in C is an interesting learning experience. You get roughly no string handling help, so you end up doing all the parsing, but you have a chance to do only the minimum amount of processing. It's sort of the opposite of the Ruby experience. To get maximum speed you end up doing things like writing frond-ends for malloc, where multiple objects you know you never have to free get allocated permanently within a malloced block. Although it is typical to use yacc(1) with C/C++, you can certainly write a recursive-descent parser and have an even deeper learning experience.

Of course, having done all that already, I'm happy to stick with Ruby these days.

Comment: Although the other answers gave me more complete answers for my all time career in parsing/compiling, this answer is what I was looking for right now.